# How to set up Sublime Text 4 for C programming?

Tags: c, sublimetext, build-system

I actually want to have the possibility of IO through ST4. I researched on the Internet for a long time but I did not find the right solution. I know that it is necessary to make a build system... I tried a lot but I didn't succeed.
[image: I have this compilers]

I have tried build system like this:

```
{
"cmd": ["bash", "-c", "clang '${file}' -Wall -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"],
"selector": "source.c",
"shell": false,
"working_dir": "$file_path",
"variants": [
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["clang", "$file", "-o", "${file_base_name}", "-Wall"]
    }
]
```

}